# In JavaScript; trying to loop adding user input name to a list of names

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, append, closures

I am trying to update and display a list of names each time the user submits a new name. For example, (first time: "Jim” is displayed, second time: “Jim Bob” is displayed, third time: “Jim Bob Joe” is displayed, etc.) It is required to use closure. I can get the pre-loaded input value, but I guess there is something wrong with my loop and I don't get any further input. Any ideas?

Enter a name and I will add it to the list:

```
        <input type="text" id="newName" value="Doug"/> 
        <button onclick="closureExample()">closureExample()</button>    
        <p id="nameList">Abe,Bill,Charlie</p>
        <script>
            var addName = (function () {
                var names = ['Abe', 'Bill', 'Charlie'];
                var name = document.getElementById("newName").value;
                var text;
                for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                    text += names[i];
                }
                return function () {return text;}
            })();

            function closureExample(){                  
                document.getElementById("nameList").innerHTML = addName();                  
            }   
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have the names array inside the closure so its not global and add your click listener inside it which can add names to the array and print them.

```
    <input type="text" id="newName" value="Doug"/> 
    <button id="add_name_btn">closureExample()</button>    
    <p id="nameList"></p>
    <script>
        (function(){
            var names = [];
            document.getElementById("add_name_btn").addEventListener('click', function() {
                names.push(document.getElementById("newName").value);
                document.getElementById('nameList').innerHTML = names.join(' ');
            });
        })();
    </script>
```

Comment: YES, this works! And I was even trying to use push and join in an earlier version, just way wrong. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
    <input type="text" id="newName" value="Doug"/> 
<button onclick="closureExample()">closureExample()</button>    
<p id="nameList">Abe,Bill,Charlie</p>
<script>
    var addName = (function () {
        var names = ['Abe', 'Bill', 'Charlie'];
        var name = document.getElementById("newName").value;
        var text;
        for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            text += names[i];
        }
        return  text;
    })();

    function closureExample(){                  
        document.getElementById("nameList").innerHTML = addName();                  
    }   
</script>
```

I changed Code return text. please , check this working.

Comment: That isn't using a closure. The IIFE runs once and returns a string. *closureExample* then calls *addName*, which is a string and can't be called.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="newName" value="Doug"/> 
<button onclick="closureExample()">closureExample()</button>    
<p id="nameList">Abe,Bill,Charlie</p>
<script>
function closureExample(){
    var names = document.getElementById("nameList").innerHTML.split(','),
        name = document.getElementById("newName").value;
    names.push(name);
    document.getElementById("nameList").innerHTML = names.toString();                 
}
</script>
```

Here is a JS fiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/passtet/kche2sx9/

Answer (score 0):

You're close.

```
var addName = (function () {
  var names = ['Abe', 'Bill', 'Charlie'];
  var name = document.getElementById("newName").value;
  var text;
  for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    text += names[i];
  }
  return function () {return text;}
})();
```

In the above, the returned function has a closure to the variables in the outer execution context, including *text*, however the value of *text* is not modified so returns the same value every time (which is the value assigned the first time the function runs).

What you want to do is update the value of *text*, then return it (note that  *text* isn't necessary, you can update *names* instead and use *join* to return a string):

```
  return function(newName) {

    // Add the new name to text
    text += newName;

    // return a string of the concatenated names
    return text;

    /* 
    ** this could be done instead
    // Update the names array
    names.push(newName);

    // Return the concatenated values in the names array
    return names.join(', ')
    */
  }
```

When the button is clicked, pass the new name to the function:

```
function closureExample() {
  document.getElementById("nameList").innerHTML = addName(document.getElementById('newName').value);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the details!!